# Generate days in month based on month

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, datetime, drop-down-menu, days

I'm wondering if anyone has an elegant solution for generating days based on a month selected for use in a dropdown. What i'm wanting to do is for the user to select the month, then populate a dropdown for days for that month. So for example if the user selected january you would have a dropdown list with values 1 - 31. The only bit i think might be tricky will be to do with leap years, so it may need to pass in year as well. Any ideas would be most appreciated :)

Comment: Why not just use the jQuery datepicker or another control that handles all of that for you?

Comment: I dont want a full date picker, i just want to be able to select year, then month then start day and end day

Comment: So use two date pickers one for the start date and one for the end date.

Comment: Sorry i didnt explain myself fully. I only ever want them to be able to select a months date range, so if they picker 2011, then November, then they could only ever pick 1 for start day and 30 for end day

Comment: You can do that with a java script function on the client side to restrict the available dates in the end date date picker.

Comment: Ah ok, i didnt know that. Thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Enumerable.Range(1, System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(int year, int month));
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to create cascading dropdowns, where the user selects the year and the month and you generate a third dropdown based on that combination.

But a much easier solution would be to use a jQuery date picker: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker

This does the hard work for you!

Answer (score 1):

Do this to populate your days dropdownlist:

```
System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(int year, int month);
```